# Opengrah - Cannot submit actions/objects for reviewing

Tags: facebook, submit, facebook-opengraph, review

When trying to submit for review, an error message occured :

"No Aggregations created for this Action Type. Please create a completed Aggregation populated with sample data before submitting for review."

Although an agreation is already there and can be previewed with sampe data !

hint : preview 'for myself' is empty, whereas for auth dialog preview user it is filled
(how can it be filled then ?)

Answer (score 2):

Goto `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/opengraph` and under 'Aggregations' you will see the aggregation you created, beside that there will be the 'Preview' call to action. Click this and create some 'Preview Objects'.

Heres an example: [image]

Note that `Product_ID` is my own custom field.

Comment: I have already created lots of preview objects, it does not help me to submit (same error). Could u submit your actions for review ?

Comment: Yep, ah ok - mine was always in english :)